# php updates all mysql rows at once but i want to update only one at a time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I added a feature to my php page to change value of "Confirmed" column from 0 to 1 when i press the submit button but it changes the Confirmed value for every record at once which i only want to do for one record at a time and the records have an unique sales id.

the code:

```
<?php
                    $conn = $pdo->open();

                    try{
                      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, sales.id AS salesid FROM sales LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=sales.user_id ORDER BY sales_date DESC");
                      $stmt->execute();
                      foreach($stmt as $row){
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM details LEFT JOIN products ON products.id=details.product_id WHERE details.sales_id=:id");
                        $stmt->execute(['id'=>$row['salesid']]);
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach($stmt as $details){
                          $subtotal = $details['price']*$details['quantity'];
                          $total += $subtotal;
                        }
                        if($row['Confirmed'] == 0){
                        echo "
                          <tr>
                            <td class='hidden'></td>
                            <td>".date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['sales_date']))."</td>
                            <td>".$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['country'].' , '.$row['city']." , ".$row['address']."</td>
                            <td width='25px;'>&#8378; ".number_format($total, 2)."</td>
                            <td width='18px;'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm btn-flat transact' data-id='".$row['salesid']."'><i class='fa fa-search'></i> View</button></td>
                            <form action='' method='post'>
                            <td width='18px;'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='confirm' value='1'> <input class='btn btn-success btn-sm btn-flat' type='submit' value='Confirm'>
                            </td>
                            </form>
                          </tr>
                         
                        ";
                        if(isset($_POST['confirm']) && $_POST['confirm'])
                        {
                          $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE sales SET Confirmed = 1 WHERE id = '".$row['salesid']."'");                                                         
                          $stmt->execute();  
                          echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";                    
                        }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e){
                      echo $e->getMessage();
                    }

                    $pdo->close();                    
                  ?>
```

Comment: take out the update inside the select statement. handle the form submission separately. you could simply just use a hidden field for the id

Comment: Tip 1: NEVER use `SELECT *` Tip 2: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query